# mysql query inside escaped bash -c string. How to put quotes?

Tags: mysql, bash, ubuntu, quotes, gnu-parallel

**Hello I am having trouble with a very specific line in a bash script.
Here is the code:**

```
ssh $SOURCEIP  "/usr/bin/time -f \"%e\" bash -c \"seq $ITER | parallel -n0 \"mysql --silent -h $TARGET -uroot -ppass -e 'SELECT * FROM dbname.tablename WHERE size = $SIZE;' >> out.txt\""
```

The problem is I ran out of quotes. The opening and escaped double quotes at the beginning of "mysql" are closing those from "bash -c". I have to put the mysql statement in double quotes and the query in single quotes, otherwise i get an error and I can't figure out how to proceed. I know that I should not pass the password like that and it will be changed later, I get this warning "$ITER"-times everytime i test this because `--silent` doesn't suppress this.
The problematic code is part of a small shell script that is supposed to just perform this data transfer.
I want to change to the other machine with ssh first and not via parallel because of consistency with other scripts.

So basically I need the double quotes around the bash -c command to get this whole parallel operation to work, which are already escaped because of the opening ssh doublequotes and also I need to put the mysql  command inside quotes as well but they are closing each other somehow.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.
Largio

**Edit: (SOLUTION)**
As suggested by @ole-tange the following command worked for me.

```
parallel --shellquote | parallel --shellquote
```

After invoking in a shell, i pasted my string in question into the prompt and got the masked string back. I still had troubles with finding out what exactly to paste but in the end it is just logical.
What exactly i pasted into the quoter was:

```
sql mysql://root:pass@$TARGET/ 'SELECT data FROM db_name.tablename WHERE size = ${SIZE};' >> out.txt
```

But still i had some problems with my variables inside my query. The problem here was that i had to de-mask the masking of the 2 variables $TARGET and $SIZE after everything got masked by the parallel quoter. Maybe my thinking has a too laborious manner but i could not get it to work in another way. Also note that i did not put quotes around the whole sql statement, as my plan was before, because now the quoter compensated for that. For consistency reasons i paste the final string that i got working in the end (with my changes afterwards):

```
ssh $SOURCEIP  "/usr/bin/time -f \"%e\" bash -c \"seq $ITER | parallel -n0 sql\\\ mysql://root:pass@$TARGET/ \\\'SELECT\\\ data\\\ FROM\\\ db_name.tablename\\\ WHERE\\\ size\\\ =\\\ ${SIZE}\\\;\\\'\\\ \\\>\\\>\\\ out.txt\""
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GNU Parallel has a quoter:

```
$ parallel --shellquote
"*\`$
[CTRL-D]
\"\*\\\`\$
```

And you can do it twice:

```
$ parallel --shellquote | parallel --shellquote
"*\`$
[CTRL-D]
\\\"\\\*\\\\\\\`\\\$
```

So just paste the string you want quoted.

But you might want to consider using functions and use `env_parallel` to copy the function:

```
myfunc() {
  size=$1
  target=$2

  sql mysql://root:pass@$target/ "SELECT data FROM db_name.tablename WHERE size = $size;" >>  out.txt
}
env_parallel --env myfunc -S $SOURCEIP --nonall myfunc $SIZE $TARGET
```

Also: Instead of `mysql` try `sql mysql://root:pass@/ 'SELECT * FROM dbname.tablename WHERE size = $SIZE;'`